# Не могу получить код .onion сайта с помощью requests

Tags: python, requests, tor

Решил научиться работать с библиотекой `requests` и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: не могу получить код страницы .onion сайта. Данный код получает код страницы `api.myip.com` и выводит его в консоль.

У меня вывело `{"ip":"66.146.193.33","country":"Unknown","cc":"XX"}` (ip состоит в сети tor)

```
import requests

tor = requests.session()
tor.proxies = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050', 'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'} # на порту 9050 запущен tor
html = tor.get('https://api.myip.com/')
print(html.text)
```

Код работает, но если я попытаюсь заменить `api.myip.com` на `3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion` (tor-зеркало DuckDuckGo) - мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: / 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x03441910>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена! Нужно заменить протокол `socks5` на `socks5h` и всё будет работать.